# How to unify the datetime format when in Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I would like to normalize my Datetime for a given database. I need to be able to use the date to do statistics. Here is what I've done so far:

```
select
 CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
    WHEN 1 then 'Pattern1'--CAST([Last Updated] AS Datetime) --2/8/2017 2:30:14 PM 
    ELSE
     CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
        WHEN 1 then 'Pattern2' --2015-03-02 03:46:38 PM
        ELSE
        CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern3'
            ELSE
            CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern4'
                ELSE
                CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern5'
                    ELSE
                    CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern6'
                        ELSE
                        CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern7'
                            ELSE
                            CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
                                WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern8'
                                ELSE
                                CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
                                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern9'
                                    ELSE
                                    CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%',[Last Updated])
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Pattern10'






END
    END
        END
            END
                END
                    END
                        END
                            END
                                END
                                    END
as 'Pattern'
```

When i am trying to cast as datetime, it gives me an error... Here are some examples:

```
Pattern1:
2/8/2017 8:06:56 AM 
2/2/2017 2:42:09 PM 
1/3/2017 9:10:20 AM  

Pattern 2:
2016-12-20 11:08:20 
2016-11-09 10:04:35 
2016-11-01 10:53:11 AM
2017-02-03 09:13:14 
2016-11-09 10:09:09 

Pattern3:
12/14/2016 11:54:53 AM
12/16/2016 11:05:24 AM
12/19/2016 12:23:51 PM

Pattern4:
8/15/2016 12:13:35 PM 
4/17/2015 12:29:54 PM 
2/22/2016 10:44:11 AM 
6/12/2014 10:08:07 AM 
9/16/2013 12:18:22 PM
```

I would like them to all be normalized to the format: '02/13/2017 11:58:00'

Is there any way of doing this??

Here is how i do to get the dates:

```
WHEN (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22))  = null THEN 'UNAVAILABLE' 
WHEN (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22))  = '' THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'
WHEN (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22))  like '%--%'
THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'

ELSE

    (Case  
    WHEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE((RTRIM(LTRIM((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22)))))),0,5) 
    --FOR AM
    LIKE '%MA%' THEN 
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22)

    WHEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE((RTRIM(LTRIM((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22)))))),0,5)
    --FOR PM
    LIKE '%MP%' THEN
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22)

    ELSE 

        (CASE
        WHEN LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22))))) <20
        THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'


        ELSE

            LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22)))),
            LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000)),LEN(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/) - CHARINDEX('---------------------------------------------',REVERSE(/**/Cast(Resolution as varchar(8000))/**/)),100)),22)))))-2)


            END)

        END)

END)

as 'Last Updated'
```

This is from a log system. I cannot really put much information since these are confidentials. But note that there are many people that are to put comments with a timestamp at the end of their comments, which includes their name and the timestamp. With the query up there, i was able to get most of the dates. Sometimes there are just no way to get the date (No timetamp at all in the log). Here is the example i can give:

```
Test Data
--------------------------------------------- 
FName LName 2/13/2017 1:19:42 PM
```

Comment: There is a very simple way of doing this:  store `DATETIME` values as a `DATETIME` datatype instead of `VARCHAR`.  You shouldn't be concerning yourself with the presentation of a `DATETIME` in the database.

Comment: if there are so many patterns, there's literally no way to know for certain the right date when an ambiguos style is used: `02-03-2017` is February 3rd or March 2nd?

Comment: It is February 13th 2017. But the thing is i do not store it as datetime because it is within some text... I am manually getting the date in a lot of text

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the text data you are trying to parse?

Comment: We're going to need more than one example. Can you edit your question and add 4 or 5 different examples?

Comment: Here, edited! i added the query i am using to get the timestamps.

Comment: Would Replacing the '-' by '/' Help SQL knowing what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simpler solution for your problem. Here is a proposition :

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, any_datetime_format) unified_datetime
from
(
    SELECT '2/8/2017 8:06:56 AM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '2/2/2017 2:42:09 PM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '1/3/2017 9:10:20 AM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '2016-12-20 11:08:20' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '2016-11-09 10:04:35' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '2016-11-01 10:53:11 AM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '2017-02-03 09:13:14' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '2016-11-09 10:09:09' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '12/14/2016 11:54:53 AM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '12/16/2016 11:05:24 AM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '12/19/2016 12:23:51 PM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '8/15/2016 12:13:35 PM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '4/17/2015 12:29:54 PM' any_datetime_format UNION
    SELECT '2/22/2016 10:44:11 AM' any_datetime_format UNION 
    SELECT '6/12/2014 10:08:07 AM' any_datetime_format UNION 
    SELECT '9/16/2013 12:18:22 PM' any_datetime_format
) t
```

If the format is not appropriate and you really need something like '2/13/2017 1:19:42 PM', you can replace '*CONVERT(datetime, any_datetime_format)*' by '**FORMAT(convert(datetime, any_datetime_format), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt')**'

Comment: I just added the the dates in a temporary table and was able to do it that way. Thanks for your help